# Manometer Equation Error

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

[image]

This is the question I was trying to solve.

[image]

This was the solution offered by the book.

When I was solving it, I applied the manometer equation at the initial level, but I got a different answer.

[image]

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong... any help is appreciated.

Comment: The pressures at points 1 and 2 are equal.

Comment: @ChetMiller isn't that the case for pressures at the initial level too?

Comment: Yes, that is the case for the pressures at the initial level too.  But that doesn't seem relevant to the analysis of the final state.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm sorry, I'm confused. Can you tell what is wrong with the way I approached the problem? Is it incorrect to apply the equal pressure concept at the initial level of liquids, in the final state?

Comment: The initial state is not relevant.  What is wrong with the way you approached the problem is that the pressure at point 1 is not equal to $P_0+\rho g (27.2-x)$.  In the final state shown in the diagram, the pressure at point 1 is $P_0+\rho g (27.2)$, where $P_0$ is the pressure at the top of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points at the same height have the same pressure only if:
1- The liquid is static. (met)
2- The liquid is continous. (met)
3- Same liquid. (not met)

You see after the initial condition changed by x, the initial level line no longer contains the same liquid on both sides, thus you can not say that at the initial level (after the the liquids dislocated) the pressure is still the same. That's why you need to apply equal pressure at 27.2cm below the surface of the liquid on the left side, as that is where the 3 conditions are met.